# NHibernate many-to-one with a composite-id entity

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

How can I map a many-to-one relationship where the "one" entity has a composite-id?
For example:

```
public class SingleEntity  
{  
  public int FirstId{get;set;}  
  public int SecondId{get;set;}  
  public string SomeData{get;set;}  
}
```

The entity `ManyEntity` has (in addition to a primaryKey) columns for both `SingleEntity`'s FirstId and SecondId, so I want to be able to mape the relationship so that `ManyEntity` would look like that:

```
public class ManyEntity  
{  
public int Id{get;set;}  
public SingleEntity Single{get;set;}  
public string Name{get;set;}  
}
```

How can I do it using NHibernate?

Answer (score 0):

Fluent allows you to specify composite id mapping using [`CompositeId()`](http://fluentnhibernate.org/api/FluentNHibernate.Mapping/ClassMap%601.htm#CompositeId) method. However, as we can read in this very method documentation:

> Note: Prefer using a surrogate key over a composite key whenever possible.

Composite ids usually require lot of effort for discussable/no gains. **If you can**, I would strongly advocate to use surrogate key. It's a lot easier.

Yet, if you're stuck with your DB schema, maybe those questions can help you:

- [Fluent NHibernate and composite ID with single column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581418/fluent-nhibernate-and-composite-id-with-single-column-name)
- [Fluent NHibernate — Saving Entity with Composite Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189824/fluent-nhibernate-saving-entity-with-composite-key)
- [Fluent NHibernate Composite ID table problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7068220/fluent-nhibernate-composite-id-table-problem)

If you google those phrases (fluent nhibernate composite id), you'll quickly find out that awful lot of links somehow also contain word **"problem"**...

Comment: The problem is the DB schema cannot be changed due to backward compatability with legacy software.  
I know SingleEntity can be mapped using composite-id, but how do I map the connection from the ManyEntity's side?